# Unjar dependencies in a JAR with prefix

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

I'm making a simple batch program that should be packed in a JAR with all dependencies inside.
JAR-in-JAR eclipse way make my program so slow, so I choosed to extract required library into my JAR. That way speed up execution but make my JAR "root" folder so verbose. To extract jar I used

```
<zipfileset excludes="META-INF/**.*" src="${dep.dir}/antlr-2.7.7.jar" />
```

and it works properly. When I try to use a prefix like that

```
<zipfileset excludes="META-INF/**.*" prefix="dep/" src="${dep.dir}/antlr-2.7.7.jar" />
```

my program crash for ClassNotFoundException as it could not found that. I try to edit the MANIFEST to add dep/ folder to the classpath but it doesnt work. Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

A Java class file must exist in a .jar file with a path that exactly matches its fully qualified name (meaning package + "." + simple class name). For instance, the class `com.example.Person` must exist in a .jar file as `com/example/Person.class`.

This means you cannot use the `prefix` attribute of `zipfileset` when including class files from another .jar.

The [Class-Path attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#classpath) of a manifest does not refer to a path within a .jar file.  It is a space-separated list of relative URLs of other .jar files (relative to the .jar containing the manifest).  A .jar file is always considered the root of a classpath entry;  there is no way to refer to a path within a .jar as a classpath entry.

I'm not sure what is so "verbose" about the root of your .jar file.  As far as I can tell, ANTLR classes only add an `org` directory to it.